# how to get this result from querying

Tags: postgresql

like the following table,

```
id   city   goods
------------------
1     a     v_1
2     b     v_2
3     a     v_3
4     b     v_4
```

How to query it to get the next following result?

```
id    a     b
------------------
1    v_1
2          v_2
3    v_3
4          v_4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this using [`CASE FUNCTIONS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE).

> is a generic conditional expression, similar to if/else statements in
>   other programming languages:

For Query :

```
select
  id,
  case when city = 'a' then goods else null end as "a",
  case when city = 'b' then goods else null end as "b"
from
  tbl;
```

[*Demo<>Fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=6e3c61ccf3f71ddc527cf7492715712f)